# How to keep android process alive

Tags: android, process

How does the apps like Swiftkey, Locker Master manages to keep process alive even after it has been removed from back stack?

They also don't use sticky notification.

Update:-
I need to keep my process alive. But in my case service is active but process gets killed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all have one or more unbound background [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

To kill those services you can go into Settings -> Apps -> Running.

However the services may be restarted at any time by other apps or system by sending a system wide message (intent). In most cases it is restarted by

- Time events
- Boot complete
- Other apps
- Other intents

In the Swiftkey case, it will be started by Android OS when it needs to show a keyboard.

**EDIT:** you can specify that a service runs in a remote process by adding this to the service definition in AndroidManifest

```
android:process="process_name_here"
```

However there is no such thing as a service that cannot be killed and can run forever. Android OS may start killing your service if it is running low on resources or the service is running for a long period of time. To overcome this, you can make a forground running service, but it needs to show a notification. It can also be killed by task managers, like you mentioned. You should instead start focusing on how to save it's state so you are able to restart it later.

Comment: Thanks Bojan for the quick reply. I have updated the question.

Comment: I have made an edit of further explaining. You can specify the service to run in a seperate proces, but there is no such thing as a service that cannot be killed.